# can I achieve this simple thing in PHP?

Tags: php, html, css

Basically, I want whatever is inside the h1 tag to duplicate to the h2 tag. So look at the example below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>whatever is inside here, needs to also be inside the H2 tag.</h1>

<h2>whatever is inside h1 tag, it should also be here</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

In my website, I have around five different heading tags that I need to copy-paste manually to each one so I want to do this just once and have them all be the same.

Comment: how many `h1` tag you have in your page?/

Comment: assing a variable to it

Comment: 3 to 5 `h1` or `h2`??

Comment: `echo $var="<h1>whatever is inside here, needs to also be inside the H2 tag.</h1>";` - `<h2>Text<?php echo $var; ?> more text</h2>` if that's what the question's about. If not, you need to give us an example.

Comment: you're welcome. I made a slight edit to that above and added `echo` in the first variable declaration.

Comment: well I have to log out. You've been given an answer below

Comment: Thank you Fred. Your answer worked.

Comment: answer, what answer? I posted a comment but you never got back to me to post it "as an answer". you accepted an answer instead making a mention about using mine. df? why do I feel short changed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *["Thank you Fred. Your answer worked. – John"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33470222/can-i-achieve-this-simple-thing-in-php/33470617#comment54726531_33470222)*

As per [a comment I left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33470222/can-i-achieve-this-simple-thing-in-php#comment54726088_33470222) in comments and with an added explanation:

Echo an assigned variable that you can pass/echo inside the `<h2>` tags:

```
echo $var="<h1>whatever is inside here, needs to also be inside the H2 tag.</h1>";

<h2>Text<?php echo $var; ?> more text</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods you achieve with. One is as suggested by `@Fred ii` one more is,

you have to bind your `h2` tags with `h1` with some class.

like this,

```
$("h2.def").html($("h1.abc").html());
$("h2.xyz").html($("h1.second").html());
```

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dd3ee/389/)

Make sure you try what is suggested by `@Fred ii`.

Answer (score 0):

What about this

```
<?php

    $h1 = "i'm Heading 01";
    $h2 = "i'm Heading 02";

?>
```

In HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <!-- <h1>whatever is inside here, needs to also be inside the H2 tag.</h1> -->
        <h1><?php echo $h1 ?></h1>

        <!-- <h2>whatever is inside h1 tag, it should also be here</h2> -->
        <h2><?php echo $h2 ?>, <?php echo $h1 ?></h2>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a variable and assign the value you want to use on your headings:

```
<?php $title = "Stackoverflow!"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>

<h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>

</body>
</html>
```

or if you want to use it to many pages, create a separate file that contains your configurations, include it where you need it.

config.php

```
<?php $title = "Stackoverflow!"; ?>
```

page1.php

```
<?php include("config.php") ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>

<h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
<p>This is page 1!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

page2.php

```
<?php include("config.php") ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>

<h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
<p>This is page 2!</p>
</body>
</html>
```